# Eric Lippert's Asynchronous Programming example

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I'm trying to understand the basics of asynchronous programming in C# using Eric Lippert's example in [Asynchronous Programming - Easier Asynchronous Programming with the New Visual Studio Async CTP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh456401.aspx) from 2011.

I've filled in stubs for the methods referenced in the last code example, and what I expect to see on the command line is:

```
Start obtain order
Finish obtain order
Start obtain ingredients
Start obtain recipe
Finish obtain ingredients
Finish obtain recipe
Start recipe prepare meal
Finish recipe prepare meal
Diner receives meal
```

but instead I see each of the methods being called in turn - nothing appears to be asynchronous.

Is there an error in my code, or have I misunderstood how it should work?

Thanks very much for any guidance.

```
namespace AsyncAwait
    {
    using System;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    internal class Program
    {
        internal class Order
        {
        }

        internal class Ingredients
        {
        }

        internal class Recipe
        {
            internal async Task<Meal> PrepareAsync(Ingredients ingredients)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Start recipe prepare meal");
                await Task.Delay(4 * 1000);
                Console.WriteLine("Finish recipe prepare meal");
                return new Meal();
            }
        }

        internal class Meal
        {
        }

        private class Diner
        {
            internal void Give(Meal meal)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Diner receives meal");
            }
        }

        async private static Task<Order>ObtainOrderAsync(Diner diner)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Start obtain order");
            await Task.Delay(3 * 1000);
            Console.WriteLine("Finish obtain order");
            return new Order();
        }

        async private static Task<Ingredients>ObtainIngredientsAsync(Order order)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Start obtain ingredients");
            await Task.Delay(2 * 1000);
            Console.WriteLine("Finish obtain ingredients");
            return new Ingredients();
        }

        async private static Task<Recipe>ObtainRecipeAsync(Order order)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Start obtain recipe");
            await Task.Delay(5 * 1000);
            Console.WriteLine("Finish obtain recipe");
            return new Recipe();
        }

        async private static void ServeBreakfast(Diner diner)
        {
            Order order = await ObtainOrderAsync(diner);
            Ingredients ingredients = await ObtainIngredientsAsync(order);
            Recipe recipe = await ObtainRecipeAsync(order);
            Meal meal = await recipe.PrepareAsync(ingredients);
            diner.Give(meal);
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Diner diner = new Diner();
            ServeBreakfast(diner);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This can't be all the code...

Comment: @ErikPhilips What do you think is missing?  The code runs fine as is.

Comment: You are awaiting each task in turn. Look closer at `ServeBreakfast`.

Comment: Why do you think you should be able to, say, prepare the recipe before you have the recipe or the ingredients?  That makes no sense.  You need the recipe and the ingredients to prepare them, and this is represented in the code.  Just because the work happens *asynchronously* doesn't mean that they can happen in any order.  It just means that they aren't blocking a thread while they do their work.

Comment: @Servy I failed to scroll the code....  my mistake.

Comment: Remember, await does not mean "run this code asynchronously". The code is already running asynchronously by the time the await is reached!  Await means "I can't go on until this task is complete, so do something else while you're waiting".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each of those `Async` methods returns a Task that can be `await`ed.
When you call `xxxAsync` method, you start the asynchronous operation, but also, when you `await` the result (which is Task) on the same line, you are telling the program "I need result of this method before continuing".

Only method I see in your example that can run in parallel are `ObtainIngredientsAsync` and `ObtainRecipeAsync`. All other methods need result of previous methods.

If you wish for these mentioned methods to run in parallel, first call both methods without `await`ing them, and then `await` them both before continuing.

```
async private static void ServeBreakfast(Diner diner)
        {
            Order order = await ObtainOrderAsync(diner);
            Task<Ingredients> ingredientsTask = ObtainIngredientsAsync(order);
            Task<Recipe> recipeTask = ObtainRecipeAsync(order);
            Ingredients ingredients = await ingredientsTask;
            Recipe recipe = await recipeTask
            Meal meal = await recipe.PrepareAsync(ingredients);
            diner.Give(meal);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are awaiting each task, one by one:

```
Order order = await ObtainOrderAsync(diner);
Ingredients ingredients = await ObtainIngredientsAsync(order);
Recipe recipe = await ObtainRecipeAsync(order);
Meal meal = await recipe.PrepareAsync(ingredients);
diner.Give(meal);
```

When you `await` a task, you stop the execution of the method until the task has finished.

So you are defining a strict one-by-one order for your tasks: you don't start a task until the previous one has finished.

Here's an example where two of the tasks are done in parallel, which should give you the output you expect.

To (hopefully) make the code more clear, I've broken up all your awaits into separate statements for creating tasks and awaiting them.

```
async private static void ServeBreakfast(Diner diner)
{
    // first task is to get the order
    Task<Order> getOrder = ObtainOrderAsync(diner);

    // we need to wait for the order, then we 
    // can get the ingredients and recipe in parallel
    Order order = await getOrder;

    // ### Change from your logic: Here we're starting two tasks in parallel. ###
    Task<Ingredients> getIngredients = ObtainIngredientsAsync(order);
    Task<Recipe> getRecipe = ObtainRecipeAsync(order);

    // once we have both the above we can make the meal
    Ingredients ingredients = await getIngredients;
    Recipe recipe = await getRecipe;
    Task<Meal> getMeal = recipe.PrepareAsync(ingredients);

    // when the meal is ready, give it to the diner
    diner.Give(await getMeal);
}
```

Comment: Your broken up version is not exactly the same, `ObtainRecipeAsync` does not start it's call till the task returned from `ObtainIngredientsAsync` completes. You might want to make it a little more clear that you are changing the behavior of the code in your new example.